# SBWebImage build-in view indicator loading animation doesn't show, SWIFT

Tags: swift, animation, sdwebimage

I am trying to get an loading animation for when an image is loading before being displayed on the view. I am using SDWebImage and I've looked at their documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/How-to-use#use-view-indicator-50) and followed the guidelines there plus searched online but it still dosen't show any loading animation.

I've set up an 4 second delay to see if the animation is activated.

```
import UIKit
import Entities
import SDWebImage

public final class MediaView: View {
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let this = UIImageView()
        this.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        this.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        this.isHidden = true
        return this
    }()

    override public func configureView() {
    super.configureView()
    }

    override public func configureSubviews() {
        super.configureSubviews()
        addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override public func configureConstraints() {
        super.configureConstraints()
        imageView.edges(equalTo: self)
    }

    public func load(_ media: Media) {
        switch media {
        case .image(let imageData):
            
            imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray <------ Loading animation here
            imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageProgressIndicator.default <------ Loading animation here
            //imageView.sd_imageIndicator?.startAnimatingIndicator()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4, execute: { [weak self] in
                self?.imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageData.url)
                self?.imageView.isHidden = false
            })
        case .unknown:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imageView` is hidden `this.isHidden = true` and you set `sd_imageIndicator` on a hidden `imageView` you make the image visible only after calling `self?.imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageData.url)` hence you dont see the indicator.

try

```
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.imageView.isHidden = false
                self?.imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
                self?.imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageData.url)
            }
```